# How to handle errors for the commands to run in Start-Job?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, start-job

I am writing an automation script. I had a function which takes either a command or an executable. I had to wait until the command or executable has completed running and return if failed or passed. I also want to write the output to file. I am trying with the `Start-Job` cmdlet.

My current code:

```
$job = Start-Job -scriptblock {
    Param($incmd)
    $ret = Invoke-Expression $incmd -ErrorVariable e
    if ($e) {
        throw $e
    } else {
        return $ret
    }
} -ArumentList $outcmd

Wait-Job $job.id

"write the output to file using receive-job and return if passed or failed"
```

This works perfectly fine for commands but for executables irrespective of errorcode the value of `$e` is null. This falsely shows as passed even though the errorcode is 0.

I tried with errorcode using `$LASTEXISTCODE` and `$?`. But `$?` is true for executables and `$LASTEXISTCODE` is either null or garbage value for commands. I am out of ideas and struck here.

Comment: You should put all your error handling logic inside the scriptblock, if you use `return $LASTEXITCODE` in the scriptblock it will come back out with `Recieve-Job`, `try{}catch{}` blocks etc. will also work, is there a reason you need to handle the errors outside the Job?

Comment: I am trying to handle the error in script block actually. But I tried with exist codes. Now I will try using try catch. Thanks

Comment: `try{}catch{}` is not working. here is my simple try.
`try{$ret=Invoke-expression $cmd}
catch{$e= "failed"}
throw $e` 
Interestingly this worked outside start-job (without throw) but inside start-job it is not throwing the `$e`

Comment: `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {try {1/0} catch {throw "Failed"}}` works fine for me, try making sure you're using `-ErrorAction Stop`, or just throw within the catch and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0):

> **$?**
>   Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.
>
> […]
>
> **$LASTEXITCODE**
>   Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.

Basically, you need to check both. `$?` indicates whether the last *PowerShell* command/cmdlet was run successfully, whereas `$LASTEXITCODE` contains the exit code of the *external program* that was last executed.

```
if (-not $? -or $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    throw '... whatever ...'
} else {
    return $ret
}
```

However, `Invoke-Expression` is not a very good approach to executing commands. Depending on what you actually want to execute there are probably better ways to do it, with better methods for error handling.

Comment: Well that's so simple thanks.

one of the executable is returing null. Is it possible for a exe to return null? Or `$LASTEXISTCODE` is not showing the exist code?

Comment: Yes, there are executables that don't return an exit code. There are also executables where non-zero exit codes don't necessarily indicate an error condition (`robocopy` for instance).